# Jquery form Validate not visible field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Form on 2 separate `<div>`, with a display none/block mechanism. The submit button is in another `<div>`.

In the first `<div>` only, some fields are with the statement `required`, so when I try to validate the form when the first `<div>` is displayed, I've got `$('#form').valid() = false`. But when the first `<div>` is in display none state and I'm trying to validate the form, I've got `$('#form').valid() = true`

I have tried to pass some params on the `valid()` function : `$('#form').valid({ignore: ""})` but always the same result.

Comment: It should be passed when the plugin is initialized `$('#form').validate({ignore: ""})`

Comment: Thansk A LOT ! It's work !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the `ignore` option to the `validate()` plugin initialization call, not to the `valid()` method

```
$('#form').validate({ignore: ""})
```